# handshake_failure after upgrading AWS Elastic Beanstalk's platform version

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ssl

I have an AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment whose current platform is `Tomcat 8 with Java 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.7.7`.

I found that after upgrading to `Tomcat 8 with Java 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.8.0`, the program on it started to show `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure` error.

Here's part of the stack trace of the error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2020)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1127)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1570)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
at com.bionime.util.notice.sms.MitakeUtil.sendMessage(MitakeUtil.java:94)
at com.bionime.util.notice.sms.MitakeUtil.sendMessage(MitakeUtil.java:132)
...
```

I've found that the JVM version on `Tomcat 8 with Java 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.7.7` is `1.8.0_161-b14`. And the JVM version on `Tomcat 8 with Java 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.8.0` is `1.8.0_171-b10`.

The tomcat version on both platforms are `Apache Tomcat/8.0.50`.

So I guess that it is the JVM version that's causing the error.

After reading [JDK 8u171 Update Release Notes](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u171-relnotes-4308888.html), I found that `3DES Cipher Suites` is disabled in `1.8.0_171-b11`. I'm guessing that handshake_failure is caused by 3DES cipher suites being disabled.

Is there anything I can do to avoid `avax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure` on `Tomcat 8 with Java 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.8.0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By removing `3DES_EDE_CBC` from the list of `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-7.b10.37.amzn1.x86_64/jre/lib/security/java.security` file, and restarting 
 Elastic Beanstalk application, this problem can be solved.

This action reenables the support for 3DES Cipher Suites.

I got this information from 
 this [article](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/384071/why-does-ucd-agent-throw-sslhandshakeexception-whe/).

---

In order to modify the list of `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` in Elastic Beanstalk, I created a file named `java-security.config` with the following content under `.ebextensions` fodler:

```
# Create a file named java-security under /usr/share/tomcat8/conf to override the default value of jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms
files: 
  "/usr/share/tomcat8/conf/java-security" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: tomcat
    group: tomcat
    content: |
      jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, DES40_CBC, RC4_40
```

This overrides the default value of `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms`, thus enabling 3DES Cipher Suites.

Then I go to elastic beanstalk environment

-> Configuration

-> Software

-> Environment properties

-> type java.security.properties for Name, and /usr/share/tomcat8/conf/java-security for Value.

-> Restart tomcat.

After the above operations, the value of `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` will be persisted in different EC2s started by Elastic Beanstalk.